# What's the difference between the maven-dependency-plugin and dependencyManagement

Tags: java, maven

I am confused about the difference between the `artifactItem` defined in  `maven-dependency-plugin` and the `dependency` defined in `dependencyManagement`/`dependencies` in maven.

My real question is why do you put `artifactItem` in `maven-dependency-plugin` -> `configuration`->`artifactItems` while you can put the `dependency` under `dependencyManagement`/`dependencies`?

Is it because that you can specify copy/pack the dependency to a specified folder using maven-dependency-plugin? If so, does it means that maven-dependency-plugin is a superset of dependencyManagement? If true, why bother to have dependencyManagement?

To make it simple, let's not consider multiple projects. Let's assume that there is only one project and one pom, it doesn't have any child project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `artifactItem` of the `maven-dependency-plugin` only applies to that specific step (e.g. unpacking that dependency or copying it somewhere). In `dependencyManagement` you can specify artifact versions etc., so that you can include them in submodules just by group and artifact id in the `dependencies` section, while the version is only configured in the `dependencyManagement` block. So technically, those 3 configuration ways (`maven-dependencies-plugin`, `dependencyManagement` and `dependencies` all serve their own purposes, neither is a superset or subset of another one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you. Although artifactItem only apply to a specific task, it is still a dependency. Is it true?

Comment: Not in the sense of project dependencies. It will not be added to the dependency tree and will not be available e.g. on the classpath, when running the application in the IDE.

Comment: So to be precise, yes, it is a dependency, but only for that specific task, not for the whole project or any other tasks.